# How to include required files for a Jenkins Job (Delphi)

Tags: delphi, continuous-integration, jenkins, build-automation

As stated in my title, basically I'm struggling on how to go about to include required files for a Delphi program to compile. I'm experimenting with Jenkins and using the execute Windows batch command for building the Delphi program (Delphi 2006 is used). It would be nice if there is some sort of generic method to find/include the required files since including it manually defeats the point of automation. Does anyone have experience with this? Or maybe know a script or batch that can include the needed files?

Thanks in advance if anyone can help!

Comment: Having the same library paths in your build machine Delphi installation and use settings from the project file is not enough?

Comment: The Delphi structure is located on a server and connection is only done via SVN, I can't have the entire structure also located locally on the build machine.

Comment: Configuring the build is usually required only once, from this point on the build happens automatic - until it breaks :) - so this is the normal way to work with CI. Or maybe the question was not clear.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "include required files". You put them into your uses clause when creating the application. You add the required paths either to your library path inside the IDE (like for commonly used 3rd party libraries/components) or the relative path to your project search path and you are done.
Or do you mean only svn get the files that are needed for the project to compile?

Comment: @StefanGlienke I know what you saying Stefan but everything works in the IDE but as soon as I try to build the project trough Jenkins it fails with message indicating ABC must be included. So how can one in a sense tell Jenkins to look also for the files that should be included

Comment: It would be helpful to see the actual message dcc puts out because it more sounds like the compile action is missing the project settings (which may include search paths). So make sure your dcc call (I don't know if Jenkins directly supports building delphi projects like for examle finalbuilder) is correct.

Comment: @StefanGlienke Thanks for replying again first of all. Sure I'll attach the message for you. Jenkins does support Delphi build by using command line such as DCC or via plugins. In the mean time I'll check Final Builder out. My reason for trying Jenkins is simply because it is free.

Comment: @StefanGlienke The Message:                                             

C:\Program Files\Jenkins\workspace\DelphiTest>cd C:\Program Files\Jenkins\workspace\DelphiTest\TestApp\ 

C:\Program Files\Jenkins\workspace\DelphiTest\TestApp>dcc32.exe -B prjTest.bdsproj -E C:\Test  
Borland Delphi for Win32 compiler version 18.0
Copyright (c) 1983,2005 Borland Software Corporation
Fatal: E2202 Required package 'dac100' not found

Comment: I guess you did not install the DevArt components (properly) on the build server - that is why it does not find the dac100 package.

Answer (score 0):

When you use dcc32.exe directly, be sure, that all required include paths are set correctly in dcc32.cfg (-I). See [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE/en/DCC32.EXE,_the_Delphi_Command_Line_Compiler).Another option would be to use msbuild to build your projects.